# 2D Isometric Movement - Move to Mouse Position

Tags: java, 2d, movement, isometric, angles

I'm developing a 2d isometric game on a engine made by myself (as a way to practice Java), however i'm stuck on what it seems to be a math problem.

I wish I could have some help on how to implement a 360 degree movement system based on Mouse Position, where the character angle will be the mouse angle, and the mouse angle is defined based on the center point the screen itself. The screen work like a compass, and where you click on it, it will set the angle and character should walk following said angle.

But trigonometry is by no means one of my strenghts, i'm struggling on how to determine the angle, then, how to set a formula to change the Y and X velocity based on the angle found.

Example, my native resolution is 512x288. Center point is 256x144. So, If I click in in the coordinate of X = 256 and Y is 0~144, the character should walk on a perfect stright line upwards. If Y is 145~288, then, a perfect line downwards.

Any help is welcome!

Edit: The camera is always fixed on the character, so it will always render on the middle of screen.

So far I've only managed to get basic movement through mouse by adding 8 hitboxes on screen, and set the angle based on which box the mouse clicked. For the speed, it's a hardcoded switch case on angle value, like, angle = 90, vel_x = 0, vel_y = -10.

[image: That's how its look's like currently]

[image: Here is how I wish I could move the character]

Comment: How have you tried converting the mouse position to a walking direction so far? Is your character positioned in a world coordinate system, or pixel coordinates?

Comment: It is positioned on pixel coordinates. So far i've got 8-way movement thru hit boxes on the screen, and setting the angle based on which hitbox the mouse clicked. Then, the Y and X velocity is hardcoded on a switch case that checks the current angle. Example, angle = 90, then vel_x = 0, vel_y = -10.